# How can I set the file menu to always show details?

Tags: windows-xp, file-management

How can I set the file menu to always show details of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Explorer:

1. Set the view of a folder to **Details**
2. **Tools** > **Folder Options...**
3. **View** tab
4. Folder Views: **Apply to All Folders**

[image: screenshot]