# How can I set XP to show details when I try to save or load a file?

Tags: windows-xp

[This SU post](https://superuser.com/questions/378857/how-can-i-set-the-file-menu-to-always-show-details) answers for folders but does not work for "file save, file open" windows.

Comment: after a quick search for "windows open save dialog default view", someone said in [this thread](http://www.winvistatips.com/open-save-save-dialog-box-default-view-t328282.html) that it's impossible to change the default view of open/save dialog. a workaround is use third party tools to do this.

Comment: Better search than mine but not the result I'm looking for :)